# What is the difference between a voltage-level translator and a logic-level translator?

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

(This is a follow-up to [an earlier question of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/50902/solution-for-level-translation-3-3v-arduino-due-5v-shield).)

I would like to use the GTL2000 bi-directional translator IC to facilitate level translation between a 3.3V circuit and a 5V circuit (including bi-directional Digital and Analog I/O, SPI, I2C lines, etc.)

Now the [datasheet of the GTL2000](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/GTL2000.pdf) convinces me that this is the right IC for the job. However, at certain points, the datasheet describes the GTL2000 as a "low voltage translator" and that it does "voltage level translation".

So before I order the part, I am trying to understand what this means -- What is the difference between a voltage-level translator versus a logic-level translator? Can I use this IC in the application I stated above?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bidirectional analog I/O"?

Comment: @DaveTweed: The "bi-directional" was a prefix for the Digital lines, and by Analog I/O, I was referring to Analog input and "Analog"/PWM-output

Comment: Just as long as you understand that the GTL2xxx devices are only going to function as a clamp for analog inputs, and probably somewhat nonlinear at that. If you want analog inputs scaled from one range to another, you'll need to use a resistive voltage divider instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that would be important! Just read through the datasheet and I think I understand why this is now. Wonder if I can find parts that incorporate multiple resistive dividers for the more-than-one analog lines in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, this will work just fine. Here is a great article on voltage level translation that [Anindo Ghosh](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/14004/anindo-ghosh) shared with me that explains all the different types of voltage translators: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scea035a/scea035a.pdf

Logic Level = Voltage Level

In a 5v system, 5v(voltage) is high(logic) and 0v(voltage) is low(logic) and same for 3.3v...